# NameError: name is not defined but first instance is fine

Tags: python, if-statement, nameerror

I'm currently going through Learn Python The Hard Way Exercises and wanted to try writing my own code to let a user choose different paths. When I run the code below, I don't get a name error for "first_decision". However, I keep getting a name error saying it's not defined for the variable "second_decision". I am running Python 2.7.10. Does anyone know why this is?

Error Here:

```
NameError: name 'second_decision' is not defined
```

Code Here:

```
print "This is the root level where we now create 3 branches of decisions. 1, 2, or anything else"

first_decision = raw_input("> ")
print "You chose %r" % first_decision

if first_decision == "1":
    print "This is the context after player makes the first choice"
    print "Once here, we can let the player make another decision. 1, 2, or 3"

    second_decison = raw_input("> ")
    print "You chose %r" % second_decision

    if second_decision == "1":
        print "This is two levels deep"

    elif second_decision == "2":
        print "This is two levels deep"

    else:
        print "Everything else for the second level"


elif first_decision == "2":
    print "This is the second context after player makes the first choice"
    print "Once here, we can let the player make another decision. 1, 2, or 3"

    second_decison = raw_input("> ")
    print "You chose %r" % second_decision

    if second_decision == "1":
        print "This is two levels deep"

    elif second_decision == "2":
        print "This is two levels deep"

    else:
        print "Everything else for the second level"

else:
    print "This is for everything else"
```

Comment: It's just a typo. second_decison != second_decision. When I get errors like that I copy the variable and search for it in the program to verify match/mismatch.

Comment: Oh my god. I am silly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong name, you assing to "second_decison" and then use "second_decision"
you missed i.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help Kacper!

Answer (score 0):

You made a typo in the line

```
second_decison = raw_input("> ")
```

This should be

```
second_decision = raw_input("> ")
```

Comment: Thank you so much Henry!